# Linking two list using V-for and v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sharepoint

Platform: SharePoint 2016

Framework: Vuejs

I work for an organization that has a blog but the weird thing is that the pictures of the authors is stored independently.

There is a column in both lists that associates the connection.
The outer v-for loops through the blog posts and the inner v-for loops through the pictures.

If the value from the outer v-for equals the inner v-for `<span v-if='blog.Name' == 'post.Category'>`, I want the image to show.
Here's the code:

```
<v-row v-for="post in postArray">
    <table style="width:100%;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px gray solid;font-size:14px">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:5px;width:80px;vertical-align:top;">
                <span v-for="blog in blogPictureArray" >
                    <span v-if='blog.Name' == 'post.Category'>
                        <img v-bind:src="blog.Name || alternateImg" v-bind:alt="post.BlogImgAlt" width="55" height="55" />
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="bloghead"><a v-bind:href="editLink + post.Id">{{post.Title}}</a></p>
                <p>by {{post.Author0  || "N/A"}} | {{convertDate(post.Created)}}
                <br />{{stripHtml(post.Body)}}<a v-bind:href="editLink + post.Id">read more</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</v-row>
```

The picture is blank but I don't get an error either so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: v-if="'blog.Name == post.Category"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to set `blog.Name` as source of an image? I have no idea what its value is, but according to its semantics that might be `My Bali diving trip` rather than `path/to/author.jpg`.

Another thing i'd got rid of declarative loop inside of loop logic. Just move it to component's method:

```
<img :src="getImgSrc(post)">
...
methods: {
  getImgSrc(post) {
    // Here check the pictureArray and return proper image path
  }
}
```

And in the end... a table design? Common it's 2020 :)

Comment: table design has its purpose depending on the requirement.  :)